# Neo4j migration from 5.5.0 to 5.11.0 - Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.cypher.mapParallel2`: Caused by:RuntimeException: Error polling, timeout

Tags: neo4j, cypher, database-migration, apoc

I'm trying to migrate from Neo4j `5.5.0` to `5.11.0` (also tried 5.10.0)

The following query works fine on Neo4j `5.5.0`:

```
MATCH  ( childD:Vacancy )  WITH collect({`childD`: childD}) as childDDgRdgd  
CALL apoc.cypher.mapParallel2(" WITH _.childD as childD 
WHERE  ( coalesce(size(childD.employmentIds), 0) <= 0  
OR  exists { MATCH (childD)-[:EMPLOYMENT_AS]-(req0:Requirable) 
WHERE req0.id IN $reqParam0}  )  AND  ( coalesce(size(childD.locationIds), 0) <= 0  
OR  exists { MATCH (childD)-[:LOCATED_IN]-(req1:Requirable) 
WHERE req1.id IN $reqParam1}  )  AND  (childD.`status` = $status5)  
AND  (childD.`active` = $active4)  AND ( (childD.`hourlyRateUsd` >= $hourlyRateUsd2)  
OR  (childD.`salaryUsd` >= $salaryUsd3) ) 
WITH childD RETURN childD  ", {`reqParam1`:[6, 7], `reqParam0`:[26], `active4`:true, `salaryUsd3`:13088, `hourlyRateUsd2`:96, `status5`:'APPROVED'}, childDDgRdgd, 6, 100) YIELD value as value   
WITH value.childD as childD  
return childD
```

But fails on Neo4j `5.11.0` with:

```
Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.cypher.mapParallel2`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error polling, timeout of 10 seconds reached.
```

I also tried to extend the timeout to 100, but with the same result.

Has anything changed between Neo4j `5.5.0` and Neo4j `5.11.0`? Maybe some additional configurations are required or something like that?

For my tests, I'm running Neo4j in Docker with:

<NEO4J_db_memory_transaction_total_max>0</NEO4J_db_memory_transaction_total_max>                               <NEO4J_server_memory_pagecache_size>2G</NEO4J_server_memory_pagecache_size>                                 <NEO4J_server_memory_heap_initial__size>5G</NEO4J_server_memory_heap_initial__size>                                     <NEO4J_server_memory_heap_max__size>5G</NEO4J_server_memory_heap_max__size>

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a bug. If neo4j 5.13 is an option you could try using the new parallel runtime instead of the apoc.cypher.mapParallel2 procedure. https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/planning-and-tuning/runtimes/concepts/#runtimes-parallel-runtime

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'll investigate this new functionality. Regarding my original question you are correct, there is a bug https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/3751